# Как работает функция getsockname()?

Tags: c++, winsock

Я создаю сокет, привязываю его к порту 33005. Далее хочу узнать к какому порту привязан сокет, но почему-то `sockaddr_in.sin_port` показывает другой результат

```
SOCKET sock = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
::sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ::inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addr.sin_port = ::htons(33005);
int error = ::bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
error = ::listen(sock, 64);

sockaddr_in addr2;
int len;
error = ::getsockname(sock, (sockaddr*)&addr2, &len);
```

Comment: Как Вы выводите результат? `inet_ntoa(addr2.sin_addr),ntohs(addr2.sin_port)` ? Какой порт показан?

Comment: Проблема решилась. Я просто посмотрел что находится в поле `addr2.sin_port`, а не использовал функцию `ntohs()`